# Scanners in ImageKit usage

Tags: macos, cocoa, scanning, imagekit

There seems to be very little documentation on the proper implementation of scanners in Apple's ImageKit framework. Could anyone please explain the subtle differences of the following:

1. ICDeviceBrowser
2. IKDeviceBrowserView
3. IKScannerDeviceView

And possibly how to use them through a small example.

Comment: Thanks Josh. Any ideas though?